# jquery msgBox execution in code behind(c#)

Tags: c#, javascript, msgbox

I want to show a message box when user enters wrong ıd or password. I write following function to the .aspx file:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function warningMessage() {
        $.msgBox({
            title: "Hatalı Giriş",
            content: "Kullanıcı numarası ya da şifre hatalı...",
            type: "error",
            buttons: [{ value: "Ok" }]              
        });
    }
</script>
```

and I write the following code to the aspx.cs file:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "warningMessage  ", "warningMessage()", false);
```

but this code does not work. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using [this plugin](http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/) it is necessary to include 3 files:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.msgBox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/msgBoxLight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I used this code on client-side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function warningMessage() {
        $.msgBox({
            title: "Hatalı Giriş",
            content: "Kullanıcı numarası ya da şifre hatalı...",
            type: "error",
            buttons: [{ value: "Okay"}]  
        });
    }
</script>
```

On server-side:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), null, "warningMessage();", true);
```

***IT WORKS WELL FOR ME***

Comment: this does not work too. but when I change the true as false it shows warningMessage(); in the web page's top part

Comment: Well it does.. Change the code of function warningMessage() to this `{ alert('Check'); }` and comment everything else.. And then try it..

Comment: Thanks but I know it. I want to give a title to message box and I learned that I must use jquery msgBox built-in method to give title.

Comment: That means the problem is not in the code-behind call... But in the jQuery you created.. And I don't know if `$.msgBox` is a function..  Till I understand you are using some plugin and haven't included its `.js` file

Comment: I have added followings to head tag and I added the files required to my project.

    <script src="/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/jquery.msgBox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

the problem may originate from $.msgBox

Comment: Which pulug-in are you using..?

Comment: I am using jquery-1.8.0.js and jquery.msgBox.js

Comment: If you have used [this plug-in](http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com) have you included the style sheet..

Comment: [link](http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/) I saw msgBox method in this site but it does not show how to use it

Comment: yes it works thanks a lot. I have added wrong file to my project
( jquery-1.8.0.js )